# How to concatenate strings in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Let's say we have two strings:

```
String1 = 'This is '
String2 = 'a mouse.'
```

How can I concatenate these 2 strings to form the string `'This is a mouse.'` in gnuplot?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Given two strings

```
String1 = 'This is ' 
String2 = 'a mouse.'
```

To concatenate them, you can use either

```
String3 = String1.String2
```

or a more flexible:

```
String3 = sprintf("%s%s", String1, String2)
```

type `help string` or `help sprintf` for more information about the two methods.

Comment: I have a scenario where this does not work: When using `columnheader(1)`, it works in `plot ... title columnheader(1)` (as does `plot ... title "Avail."`), but it does not work trying to concatenate `columnheader(1)` and `"Avail."`. Message like `f_sprintf: attempt to print numeric value with string format`... (The first column of my data file contains a fixed string like `"/var"` (with those double-quotes))

Comment: Found the solution: Using `columnhead(1)` instead of ` columnheader(1)` fixes the problem, even though I don't understand.