# Call Gnuplot script passing target data file as as parameter

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, plot, gnuplot

I have a set of directories (`dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `...`) containing data files (`data.csv`).

I would like to plot that data using Gnuplot. So I composed the following script:

```
set term png # size 1024,480

set xlabel "time"
set ylabel "corrected value"

set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set format x "%Y"

set datafile separator ";"


set output "data_full.png"
      plot "data.csv" using 1:3 w p

set yrange [-0.1:3]
set output "data.png"
      plot "data.csv" using 1:3 w p
```

Instead of having multiple copies of this script (for each target directory) how to manage things so that I can have just one script to which I pass the target filename.

No problem if someone comes with a Python solution to deal with this script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12328603/2604213

Comment: Also helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36138334/concatenate-2-strings-in-gnuplot