# What is the difference between `columnhead(N)` and `columnheader(N)`?

Tags: gnuplot

In Gnuplot 5.2 you can use `plot "datafile" ... title columnheader(1)` to display the string in first in datafile as key. However when you try to append a string like in `plot "datafile" ... title columnheader(1) . "X"`, it fails with `unexpected ot unrecognized token`.

However when I use `plot "datafile" ... title columnhead(1) . "X"` it works!

So what is the difference between `columnheader(N)` and `columnhead(N)`, and why do both exist?

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36138352/6607497

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help text tries to explain this. `columnhead(x)` is a string-valued function. As such it can be composed or combined with other functions.

```
gnuplot> help columnhead
 `columnhead(x)` may only be used as part of a plot, splot, or stats command.
 It evaluates to a string containing the content of column x in the first line
 of a data file. See `plot datafile using`.
```

Note that this function can be used anywhere in the plot command, not just as a title option.  For a contrived example:

```
plot DATA using 1:2:(columnhead(3)) with labels
```

By contrast the keyword `columnheader` is valid only as a title option. The common use is as an option to the `set key` command in the form

```
set key autotitle columnheader
```

where it would affect all plot components generated from data files (as opposed to functions). As a convenience it is also allowed as a title substitute for a single plot component, as in

```
plot DAT1 using 1 title "foo", DAT2 using 2 title "baz", DAT3 using 3 title columnheader
```

A drawback of this is that the program has to guess which column is meant.  It is unambiguous in the example above, but consider:

```
   plot DAT3 using ($2+$3)/($4) title columnheader  # _which_ columnheader?
```

So as a special case the program looks to see if a particular column in parentheses immediately follows the keyword. I.e. it looks like a function but isn't really. The program could be smarter and realize that it could use the actual function `columnhead()`, but unfortunately it isn't that smart.

Comment: So would you agree that any occurrence of `columnheader(N)` can be replaced with `columnhead(N)`? So it seems to me that `columnheader(N)` was superseded with `columnhead(N)`, but was left intact for compatibility.

Comment: Yes, at least for the current source.  I'm not sure how many versions back this was true for.  They are converging but not yet identical.  I see now (24 hrs later) that I wrote "columnhead" in my answer in most of the places where I meant to write "columnheader", thus proving how confusing it is.  Now corrected.